# How to set the locale for Vue-i18n after I get it from a remote server?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vue-i18n

I saw many examples how to configure vue-i18n. I'm using Nuxt, so I do it like [this](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/integrations/nuxt3).

*<sub>plugins/i18n.ts</sub>*

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(({ vueApp }) => {
  const i18n = createI18n({
    legacy: false,
    globalInjection: true,
    locale: 'en',
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages: {}
  })

  vueApp.use(i18n)
})
```

I have a case where I want to store user's preferable language at a remote server in database. Is there any way to get it and configure Vue-i18n after? The problem is not retrieving the preferable language, but how to set it up after I get it.

For example, when I do it like this, all the text starts to change during the page load.

*<sub>layouts/default.vue</sub>*

```
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
const i18n = useI18n();
const appConfig = useAppConfig();

await axios({
    url: appConfig.api.baseUrl + 'language/preferable',
    method: 'get'
}).then((response: any): void => {
    i18n.global.locale.value = response.data.data.locale;
}).catch((error): void => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

But I want to wait till I get the preferable locale and init i18n only after this.
I have a more complicated code. I store the locale in a cookie after retrieving it etc. These pieces of code are just examples.

I tried to use the code as above, but this is not actually what I want. I want to get the user's preferable locale via a remote server and init the Vue-i18n plugin only after that.

Comment: you check this part of nuxt/i18n server-side translations
https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/guide/server-side-translations

Comment: I don't think this is what I need. I could not find any info about how to get the locale from a remote server. And I don't use nuxt/i18n. I use Vue-i18n. I know that nuxt/i18n is a wrapper for Vue-i18n with a lot of features, but I use only the original Vue-i18n.
Thanks anyway!